# Help me identify this font or something close to it?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification

I'm looking for the font 1:30 in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Plhgyp0KNQQ:
[image]
The Adam Tensta text is in a font that I think is used in the [old game Street Fighter](http://old.jasongordon.com/static/sf2/images/street_fighter.gif), but I'm not sure, and I can't find it or something even close to download.
Do I need to create it myself? Or is there a font out there like this?

Comment: The guy who made the video can be contacted at: info@maceofrost.com ... you could always ask him :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that's a font. It appears to be hand-drawn. You may be able to find a font possessing some of the qualities of those letterforms, but it probably won't have the overall desired effect, because it won't have any of the ligatures, "swooshes", etc.

If you want to find something close, I suggest you start [here](http://new.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Apaint/fonts/).

Comment: okej thanks, but if I find one that looks like this one, i could try to fix the last brushes my self :)

Comment: It's definitely lettering and unless someone made a font based on that particular lettering, you're better off just making your own. The letterforms are so different that there likely isn't an existing typeface to base it off of.